# Defining columns for a variable number of items, all in one row, equally spaced

Tags: css, css-grid

I am having a hard time describing what I am looking for (searching on Google)

I have dynamic logo content, it could be 3 logos, it could be 7.. My template needs to accommodate them all, They all need to display in one row equally spaced..

So for example if I knew in advance I had 3 items my code would be this

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

if I knew in advance I had 7 items my code would be this

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

I won't know how many items I have ever.
So how can I code this to accommodate a dynamic amount of columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This configuration is suitable for Flexbox where all you need to do is

```
.wrapper {
  display:flex
}
.wrapper img {
  flex:1;
}
```

Using CSS grid you have to do

```
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
}
```

You consider a column flow and you define the width of column to be equal to `1fr`

```css
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-gap:5px;
  margin:10px;
}

.wrapper span {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dai the goal here is to no have wrapped items : *They all need to display in one row equally spaced..* (note the "one row")

Answer (score 3):

Use `grid-auto-columns: 1fr`.

The grid container itself will create columns, as necessary, and each column will be `1fr`.

No need to define your own columns. Let the grid to the work.